# Automaticlly Perform Click Event On JButton within specific time period

Tags: swing, jbutton

Hi I am creating a application in swing that open a particular url in JeditorPane. Now i want it auto matically reload JEditorpane Content. My code for performing click on button is

```
loadButton = new JButton("Load");
      loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
           {
                try
                {
                     // remember URL for back button
                     urlStack.push(url.getText());

                     editorPane.setPage(url.getText());


                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                     editorPane.setText("Error: " +e);
                }

           }

      });
```

I want it execute in every 30 second. How can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

Re-use the Action/-Listener in a Timer

```
 Action loadAction = new AbstractAction("Load") {
       public void actionPerformed(...) {
            // do stuff
       }
 }
 JButton loadButton = new JButton(loadAction);
 Timer timer = new Timer(30000, loadAction);
```